# Second Order Differential equation R

Tags: r, differential-equations

I am trying to use R to solve the differential equation:

> x'' + 5x = 0
>
> x(0) = 0
>
> x(1) = 2

I am using the package deSolve, but just cannot seem to get a grasp on how to set up a system.

Comment: you need to decompose it into a system of two first-order equations (i.e. x'=y; y' =-5*x; with corresponding initial conditions)

Comment: At the moment I can't see off the top of my head how to convert your ICs into a pair of ICs with respect to x and x' at time zero (math question, not programming question)

Comment: except for the IC issue this seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756058/any-r-package-to-solve-variable-coefficients-second-order-linear-ode